# Обработка строки

Tags: javascript

```
  parts = source.split(':')
  normilized_parts = parts.map(function(num) {
    var value = +num;
    if (isNaN(value)) {return source;}
    return value;
  })
  return normilized_parts.join(':');
}

var n_num = normilize(num);
```

данный код приводит текст вид '01:0001:00004:0003' к '1:1:4:3' как обработать ситуацию когда приходят лишние символы, Вида '01:0001:00004:0003/00'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто делать `parseInt`, он отбросит все "лишние" символы

```
const str = '01:0001:00004:0003/00';
const parts = str.split(':');

const parsedParts = parts.map((num) => {
    const value = parseInt(num, 10);
    return isNaN(value) ? undefined : value;
});

const result = parsedParts.join(':');
```

С таким способом важно чтоб символ не "ломал" значение, ибо `"0/3"` спарсится в `0`, а не в `3`. Если набор символов и возможные позиции известны, то их можно просто убирать через `slice` или `replace`.

Comment: зачем пустую строку вторым параметром передавать в map? зачем `.toString()` делать?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, исправил. Изначально сделал через `reduce`, но вышло малочитабельно и когда переделывал упустил эти моменты.